# I want first name first letter and second in name in single cell

Tags: excel

I have first name & second name in one cell, I want to create first name first letter and second name in second cell.

For example: john smith is in A1 cell
I want jsmith in b1 cell

Answer (score 1):

This is your formula:

```
 =LEFT(A1,1)&MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,LEN(A1))
```

[image]